# How to choose between multiple correct answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer, fastest-gun

I recently asked a fairly [simple question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23697069/for-html-attributes-with-only-one-possible-value-can-the-value-be-omitted) on Stack Overflow that received several similar answers. All were correct but some were slightly (very slightly) more informative than others. In this case, which answer should I go for?

Usually, I'd say that the most comprehensive answer should be chosen. But when the answer is so simple that it's essentially repeated by each subsequent poster, doesn't this favour the person who answered first? In this case, I felt like the second answer containing the 3 links was a little more complete, but since it was essentially the same as the first answer, I selected the latter.

What's the recommended course of action for SE sites when it comes to accepting an answer?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Accept whatever answer helped you the most, that you felt was the most useful, the most understandable, etc.  If an answer merely duplicates an earlier answer, and doesn't add value over it, then such an answer may not be helpful to you.  If a post is later but has additional information, context, quality, detail, clarity, etc. that results in it *being more helpful to you* then it's adding value.

At the end of the day you are given wide latitude to determine what is most helpful to you.

Comment: A major purpose of acceptance and voting is to guide future readers of the question to the most useful answer. They don't care which was first, just which is most likely to fully answer a similar question.

Comment: And what if I got two useful answers but none of them was really perfect for me but together gave me an idea and I created a third solution? I don't want to answer my own question then accept it because the merit is not mine and both the answers was OK.

Comment: @TamásG. That's your decision to make.  There is no right/wrong answer.

Comment: What about the case where there are multiple legitimate answers (objectively)? Does this mean the question does not have enough detail?

Comment: @ryanwebjackson No.  If there is no way to determine if an answer is objectively correct or not *then* it doesn't have enough detail.  But there being multiple verifiably correct answers is not in and of itself a sign that the question is missing information.  (Note of course that whether or not it's *useful* isn't going to be objective; its correctness should be, but it's usefulness is quite subjective.)

Comment: I'm saying assuming there is, but there are legitimately multiple answers. I've encountered questions like this, and they effectively become a forum. Should these get moderator attention?

Comment: @ryanwebjackson A question isn't, lacking enough detail, as you specifically asked about.  It might have other problems, or it might not.  It would depend.  It's *possible* that the question is too broad, or it's possible that it's sufficiently narrow.  Lots of good questions can have multiple different answers, but so can lots of bad questions.

Answer (score 8):

Accept the best original answer and vote for any others that have substantial relative value - whether alternative solutions or enhancements.

I've often put up solutions of the latter kinds. I don't expect OP to accept them. As in this case :).

Just my opinion.

Comment: How meta of you.