# How to choose right answer?

Tags: discussion

I posted a question a year ago. It wasn't resolved because it was related with one famous web-kit bug. One guy showed me it in the answer. I marked this answer as correct. And now one other guy answers on this question again. His answer isn't right completely but he has shown me direction. I've changed my example and now it works. What should I do?

**UPDATE:**
This is original question. My solution below last answer. [Bug with transform: scale and overflow: hidden in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16687023/bug-with-transform-scale-and-overflow-hidden-in-chrome/24056662)

**UPDATE:**
Guys, this question not the same as [How to choose between multiple correct answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255150/how-to-choose-between-multiple-correct-answers). Because I don't care how to choose between two correct answers, I just try to understand. If I marked an answer as correct (and it was so), but now things have changed and the answer is no longer valid, what exactly I should do? Unmark this answer and explain why or leave things as they are.

Thank you very much. And sorry if something isn't clear.

Comment: Which answer is accepted is completely up to you, as is well explained in the other question: **"Accept whatever answer helped you the most"** - If the newer answer helps you more than the information about the bug, then by all means accept it. It's *your* checkmark and you can award it to whichever answer you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

You should choose **the most complete and correct Answer**, if there are two correct answer choose the best one ( which explain why you have this problem and it give a solution with a good explanation )

Comment: Yes, I know. But problem is to choose between 2 incorrect answers. When I asked this question a year ago, It was impossible to resolve my question because there was known web-kit bug. So I have marked the answer as correct where there was link to this bug on Chrome bug-tracker. Today another guy has answered on this question and it hasn't resolve the issue, but I have found the correct answer by myself.

Comment: What exactly I should do?
1. Answer on this question by myself and mark this as correct.
2. Leave the first answer as correct (but now it isn't correct)
3. Mark the newest answer as correct, but leave my comment with the correct example under this answer?

Comment: you can disable the solved mark

Comment: Issue was solved finally today, but it was solved by me )) Ok, I've added link to my question, may be it would easier to understand what I mean.