# Up-voting Etiquette for multiple useful answers

Tags: discussion

On a few occasions, I have asked a question on SO that has had multiple useful answers (in some cases, they've been practically identical). In this situation, what is the correct etiquette for up-voting, never mind choosing an accepted answer? Do you;

1. Up Vote only one, based on the time of the answer (and accept
   whichever one you personally used)
2. Up Vote only one, based on    which one you personally used and
   accepted
3. Up Vote them all,    they're only virtual points and
       there's no limit

Will giving them all a positive vote change the balance of the usefulness for future readers? Is there any downside? What would you guys do?

Comment: Related: [How to choose between multiple correct answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255150/how-to-choose-between-multiple-correct-answers)

Comment: Thanks @Glorfindel, they are indeed similar. However, that question seems to focus more on which answer to accept - I guess what I'm really asking is, is it acceptable to, once you have accepted your preferred answer, to upvote all other helpful or **similar** (similar being key) answers?

Comment: Yes, sure. They're your votes, you decide what to do with them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tooltip on the upvote button says:

> This answer is useful

Let that be your guide to the question you are asking:

> I have asked a question on SO that has had multiple **useful** answers

Emphasis is mine.

---

Your votes are your own, but if the answer is helpful to you, I don't see a reason not to provide an upvote.

Comment: Thanks =) I had wondered, probably somewhat pointlessly, that by upvoting multiples of essentially the same answer, if it in any way diluted the helpfulness of the voting system.