# Accept more than 1 answer

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, upvotes

My question is just what has been outlined above.

In multiple instances, I've seen that multiple answers offer alternative explanations, and many of them work and it's not possible to pick one among them as the best. Sometimes, a combination of multiple answers solves the OP's problem.

In such cases, I think such a feature to accept more than one answer would be nice.

Is there any potential downside to such an option that I don't understand?

P.S. I've gone through [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255150/how-to-choose-between-multiple-correct-answers) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319580/up-voting-etiquette-for-multiple-useful-answers) similar questions, but they deal more with the etiquette of upvoting and accepting than discussing possible alternative features.

Comment: Do not worry about down-votes in meta. They do not impact your reputation nor your account.

Comment: And in FR questions votes are usually used to express agreement/disagreement, besides their usual purpose.

Comment: Question's author is more eagerous for getting the answer. If he/she gets the answer then it got accepted. Acceptance doesn't always mean that is perfect answer but it fulfills the question's requirements. Comparison and generation of `Best answer` from other answers require more cost and it is not necessary. Instead of that voting plays very important role. Future viewers of answer do that comparison and votes accordingly. So best answer gets more vote. Acceptance of answer doesn't mean that is perfect answer. (it is written in Tour of website).

Comment: You can undo the acceptance of previous answer and can further choose different answer as accepted answer. This facility is available there.

Comment: If answering your question required bits and pieces out of different answers then your question was probably poorly asked in the first place. If there were multiple complete solutions to your problem cohesively answered by multiple people in different ways then pick the one that helped the most. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/48270127/2191572 as an example of the latter.

Answer (score 0):

All answers to a question can be good or different. The point of accept is to reward the user because *their answer worked for you*. If you liked all the answers, you can up vote them, but accepting should be the best answer.

Another point of accepting answers is for other users who come across your question. They want to see the best answer, comparatively at the top - the OP's accepted answer, then *other good* answers below it that are highly up voted.

Because you get reputation from accepting answers (+15 for post, +2 for accepter), this could lead to reputation farming, with new users where they just accept every answer to get more reputation even if the answers were poor because they get +2 for every answer.

Comment: Regarding the last point, that could be mitigated by only giving +2 for _any number_ of accepted answers.

Comment: True true. But the other points...